# CI/CD with ASP.Net Core 1.1 / VS 2015 app to Azure App Service?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, continuous-delivery

I come from a .Net development (4.X) background but do not have that much exposure to .Net Core.

Currently I have been assigned the task of taking a ASP.Net Core 1.1 app that was written using Visual Studio 2015 and enable CI/CD to make it an Azure App Service.

The areas where I need help are the TFS Build vNext steps and the Release Management.

Please help me with some samples that I can look at and accomplish the above task.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a moment and read [On Topic Helpcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. At a minimum post your previous attempts how you have tried to solve the issue and where exactly you are having a problem with. Do not ask for examples or tutorials, it is off-topic on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

For using continuous integration (CI) provided by TFS to build your ASP.NET Core application, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-core?tabs=vsts) to create a new build definition. For setting up the continuous deployment of your ASP.NET Core to Azure web app using TFS, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps).